# React: Render repeating elements from a child array based on the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Based on the current URL, find the matching "url" value in the array and repeat the child array for that value.  In the sample below, the child array is "images".

**Example JSON File**

```
const Food = [
    {
        'title': 'Vegetables',
        'url': 'edible-vegetables',
        'image': '/img/vegetables.jpg',
        'images': [
            {
                'name': 'Carrot',
                'image': '/img/carrot.jpg'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Spinach',
                'image': '/img/spinach.jpg'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 'Fruit',
        'url': 'edible-fruit',
        'image': '/img/fruit.jpg',
        'images': [
            {
                'name': 'Apple',
                'image': '/img/apple.jpg'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Pear',
                'image': '/img/pear.jpg'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Cherry',
                'image': '/img/cherry.jpg'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Example Page with Repeater**

*Please Note: This does not work, I'm including it to show where I'm getting hung up.  It repeats all the child array elements "image" and renders 5 items.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Food from './Data/Food';

class Gallery extends Component {

    state = {
        Food
    };

    render() {

        const foodRepeater = this.state.Food.map((item) => 
            item.images.map((images, index) => 
                <li key={index}>
                    <h1>{images.name}</h1>
                    <img src={images.image} alt="{images.name}" />
                </li>
            )
        )

        return (
            <>
                <section></section>
                <section>
                    <ul>
                        {foodRepeater}
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section></section>
            </>
        ); 
    }

}

export default Gallery;
```

**Desired Result**

*for... site.html/edible-vegetables render*

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Carrot</h2>
        <img src="/img/carrot.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Spinach</h2>
        <img src="/img/spinach.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

*for... site.html/edible-fruit render*

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Apple</h2>
        <img src="/img/apple.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Pear</h2>
        <img src="/img/pear.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Cherry</h2>
        <img src="/img/cherry.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to compare within your first map if the item.url matches the one you are looking for in the food repeater. Lets say you have a state element that knows the url of where you are at.

```
const foodRepeater = this.state.Food.map((item) => 
        this.state.url === item.url ? item.images.map((images, index) => 
            <li key={index}>
                <h1>{images.name}</h1>
                <img src={images.image} alt="{images.name}" />
            </li>
        ) : ''
    )
```

This code will check if your state URL is the same as the item.url and if it is it will execute the item.images.map()

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically set `state.url` based on the actual URL.  This method works, but I can't hard code `state.url`

Comment: You can extract the url from the location object in JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: I did that.  i'm able to grab the lastIndexOf the problem is i'm uncertain how to set that as `state.url`.

Comment: You don’t need to do that! In your render do const currentUrl = window.location.href; then in your map do currentUrl === item.url

Comment: Also get familiar with window.location its a very powerful thing. Console.log it and look at it in dev tools

Comment: Gotcha. I'm very familiar with window.location, just wasn't thinking i could just apply the var in the map that way.  I was initially trying to apply it to the state.  all is good now.  thanks!

Comment: No worries! Have fun, sounds like a fun project you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

create a functional component (EDIT: to filter the array for the url first):

```
 export const FoodRepeater = (props) => {
    return (
        props.food.filter(v => props.url === v.url).map((item) => 
             item.images.map((images, index) => 
                <li key={index}>
                    <h1>{images.name}</h1>
                    <img src={images.image} alt="{images.name}" />
                </li>
            );
    )
}
```

Then import that into your Gallery component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {FoodRepeater} from './FoodRepeater';

import {Food} from './Data/Food';

class Gallery extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <section></section>
                <section>
                    <ul>
                       <FoodRepeater food={Food} url='edible-vegetables' />
                       <FoodRepeater food={Food} url='edible-fruit' />
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section></section>
            </>
        ); 
    }

}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: This renders all 5 `<li>` regardless of the URL it's using.  Not sure if i'm missing something but the desired result is it would only render the `images` in the child array based on the url.

Comment: sorry, you should filter it first:
export const FoodRepeater = (props) => {
    return (
        props.food.filter(v => props.url === v.url).map((item) => 
             item.images.map((images, index) => 
                <li key={index}>
                    <h1>{images.name}</h1>
                    <img src={images.image} alt="{images.name}" />
                </li>
            );
    )
}